# regex problem finding tags like html in BeautifulSoup (customizeable)

Tags: python-3.x, regex, beautifulsoup

```
>>> l
'{{ftext{{stext}}something}}'
>>> re.findall('{{.*?}}',l)
['{{ftext{{stext}}']
```

The result is expected like `['{{ftext{{stext}}something}}','{{stext}}']` where html parser of BeautifulSoup works exactly like. But I don't know the way customizing BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match balanced overlapped strings between `{{` and `}}` with [PyPi regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module only since `re` does not support recursion:

```
import regex
l = '{{ftext{{stext}}something}}'
print( regex.findall(r'{{(?>(?!{{|}}).|(?R))*}}', l, overlapped=True, flags=regex.S) )
# => ['{{ftext{{stext}}something}}', '{{stext}}']
```

See the [online Python demo](https://tio.run/##JYxBDsIgEADvfcV6KhjSi2fkD@oHSLpQEgpkQVNDeTvW9DSXmUnfssRw692tKVIBQovb4EHCWKspuJVa8x@t5bhiWVywrY1DIhcKO/XJuDBr7xkdDVN3pi617q3xaWfqwfn1CAR4AfGD5HVKOMsXvVGA8dpmeU6eHHjvPw)

**Details**

- `{{` - `{{` string
- `(?>(?!{{|}}).|(?R))*` - zero or more repetitions of

  - `(?!{{|}}).` - any char that does not start a `{{` or `}}` char sequence
  - `|` - or
  - `(?R)` - the whole regex pattern recursed
- `}}` - `}}` string.

Comment: What if the `l` var is a segmentation? What if there's more like that inside `ftext`'s curly bracket? Will it work there too?

Comment: @AbdullahALShohag `l` is the string youprovided. It will work, test it yourself.

Comment: Technically I solved my problem, but it wasn't much helpful. What I was trying to do, I did that entirely in a different way.